# Truncate text if text goes to the next line (resizing window)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to truncate a line of text, if the window is shrunken.

In reference to this site: https://css-tricks.com/flexbox-truncated-text/#demo

My code looks similar:

[image]

However, instead of one **h2** tag, I have two **span** texts in the flex-child tags:

```html
<span> testingtexthereherehehrhehr </span>
<span> MOREtestingtexthereherehandhere </span>
```

I have tried to do **.flex-child > span**, but when I shrink the window the 2nd **span** simply goes to the next line. I would like it to stay on 1 line and just truncate with the "..."

Any guidance would help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For your text to have a line break, it needs to be inside an `HTML` tag that is a `block`, like the `<div>` tag for example.

In your example, using a , you need to declare in `CSS` as - `display: block`;

Comment: How come it wouldnt work if display was flex?

Comment: The white-space: nowrap; is making sure you don't break the line

Answer (score 0):

Overflow only applies to block level elements, (`span` is not block level).

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow):

> The text-overflow property only affects content that is overflowing a
> **block** container element in its inline progression direction (not text
> overflowing at the bottom of a box, for example).

You also need to have set a size that can be overflowed by your text and (as you do already have), you need to specify the `white-space` and `overflow` properties in order for `text-overflow` to work.

```css
div { 
  width: 100px;
  
  /* Both white-space and overflow are required
     in order for text-overflow to work. */
  white-space: nowrap; 
  overflow:hidden; 
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div> MORE testing text here here and here k jsd;fdslkjf sd;flkjsd f;lsdkfj sd;lfkdjs f;lsdkfj sd;lfksdj f;ldskfj ds;lfksdj f;ldskfjd s;lfkdsjf ;ldskfj ds;lfksdjf ;ldskfj sdl;fksdjf ;lsdkfj sd;lfkjsd fl;sdkjf ds;lfkjsd ;flkdsjf sdlkfjds ;flkdsjf ;ldskfj sd;lfkjds ;lf</div>
```

Comment: Ah, makes sense that span wouldnt work as its not a block.

But in your code snippet, would I have to add the white space, overflow, and text overflow to both the flex parent and flex child since they are both divs? Currently I have my flex parent as display: flex

Comment: @webdesignnoob You should have those CSS properties set for the actual element(s) that contain the text that might overflow, so most likely the flex-child.

Comment: When I make my width small, I do see the ellipsis, but when I make my width a size so that my text can be fully read in full screen, then shrink the screen, the ellipsis does not appear. The text is getting pushed and disappears if the screen is too small.
Would you have any idea why this would happen? I tried changing my display to block, but that messes up my other components.

Comment: @webdesignnoob I'm not sure, but it could very well be because of the `display:flex`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the following works (on Vue 2). None of above answers.

```html
<div style="word-break: break-all !important;">Some text example</div>
```